# tcl compilation error in android build environment

Tags: android, linux, tcl

I am able to compile tcl8.6.1 source using GNU Makefile for X86 successfully. Also able cross compile for arm using Android standalone tool chain with make.
When I try to build the same tcl source using Android environment by writing my own Android.mk file and with "mm" command, i am seeing "error: expected ')' before '->' token" error. Detailed error log is given for reference. Please suggest how and where it can go wrong.

```
system/extras/work/tcl8.6.1/unix/../generic/tclOODecls.h:183:16: error: expected ')' before '->' token
  (tclOOStubsPtr->tcl_NewObjectInstance) /* 13 */
                ^
system/extras/work/tcl8.6.1/unix/../generic/tclOO.c:1562:1: note: in expansion of macro 'Tcl_NewObjectInstance'
 Tcl_NewObjectInstance(
 ^
system/extras/work/tcl8.6.1/unix/../generic/tclOODecls.h:157:16: error: expected ')' before '->' token
  (tclOOStubsPtr->tcl_CopyObjectInstance) /* 0 */
                ^
system/extras/work/tcl8.6.1/unix/../generic/tclOO.c:1840:1: note: in expansion of macro 'Tcl_CopyObjectInstance'
 Tcl_CopyObjectInstance(
 ^
make: Leaving directory `/local/mnt/workspace/Code/TAG_JUNE_15'
```

make failed to build some targets (38 seconds)

Comment: Any reason for not building 8.6.5 instead? It's had a few fixes since 8.6.1…

Answer (score 0):

That file (`tclOODecls.h`) is an auto-generated C header file that describes the C Interface to the TclOO part of the Tcl API. The error indicates that something is not handling the `tclOOStubsPtr` token well, which is exceptionally strange; it should be a variable that is defined in the stub library. There's something horribly wrong, and given that you appear to be the only person with the problem, I'm guessing it is in your configuration or how you are using it.